# Lion and sun hammered coin

Tags: mughals

What is origins of antique gold medallion (or may be pendant, or seal, or coin)? It is one sided and hammered lion holding sword and heading to right. The lion has sun behind. There is no inscription and crown on medallion.

Comment: You really should include a photography of the object of good enough quality to see its details.

Comment: Trying to upload pic. But it's impossible,  something is wrong

Comment: IIRC correctly, you need 10 reputation to upload an image (to protect from spam). If another user upvotes your question, you will be able to include the image directly. If not, you can put an URL to the image in a comment and another user can put it into the question.

Comment: You should be able to post a picture now. Also, you should tell what you know about the piece (where it does come from, if you know its aproximate age, ..)

Comment: I'm really sorry. But it seems I'm dummy. Couldn't upload again. May be doing something wrong.

Comment: Anyway,  i have almost no info about this item. I don't even know whether it's pendant or medallion, coin or seal. I guess it's medallion. Hammered, one sided, nothing written. Must be antique since it's not symmetric cause not machine made, definitely handmade

Comment: So the emblem resembles [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion_and_Sun), but no crown overhead as in coins seen [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=gold+coin+lion+holding+sword&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjckNG59-3eAhUHTt8KHZgRAZoQsAR6BAgEEAE&biw=1366&bih=626#imgrc=F2vEocJGoDWwuM:) ?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion_and_Sun

Comment: I reviewed those emblems. They have Qajar crown on the top. Mine doesn't have any. I read all available info. Couldn't find any resembling one. I just guess it has some relations with either Qajar or Mughals. I'm confused since it has only one side.

Comment: @Jale Please have a look at this [help site - section 'Images' at the bottom](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) - maybe that helps when editing your post  and inserting the image. Otherwise, you could upload it elsewhere and just post a link here. I am sure, an other user will help you and insert it here.